# how to add logout link in topmenu in header section?

Tags: magento

I don't want to add toplinks in my site but i want a logout option in topmenu.i have added a logout option in topmenu but it is not functioning....so how to make logout link in topmenu functionable? if anyone knows this , please help me out.
thanks!

Comment: Post the code you tried

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this it  will 100% work, i used it many times

```
 <?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo 'Log OUT'; ?></a>

        <?php 
    /*
    else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">SIGN IN</a>
        <?php 
    */
    endif; ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It’s really simple. You can add following piece of code in your phtml file where you want to add this log out link.

```
    <?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo 'Log OUT'; ?></a>

    <?php 
/*
else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">SIGN IN</a>
    <?php 
*/
endif; ?>
```

[SOURCE](http://magentoquiz.com/question/how-to-add-a-logout-link-anywhere-in-my-magento-store/)

Comment: when i added the above code in my page showing
Fatal error: Undefined constant '�customer' in E:\xampp\htdocs\princemagento\electronix\app\design\frontend\default\electronix\template\page\html\topmenu.phtml on line 83

Comment: @user3129737 I am not really sure what you're trying to tell me. Can you please try to explain?

Comment: I have added the above code in topmenu.phtml page but it is showing the fatal error undefined constant '�customer'

Comment: please help me it is very urgent

Comment: thanks the above code works but initially i want to show login in that place

Comment: Just remove comment for  else part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45181/discussion-between-user3129737-and-amit-bera)